# Global variables in Python to share variable across files

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a Python script that gets a command line argument, and then it is stored as a global variable within the script:

```
global chain
chain = sys.argv[1]
```

The script then imports a couple of other files, each containing another function. I am trying to carry the value of this variable to the other functions as well, by doing the following:

```
def func():
    global chain
    #do stuff
```

which is contained in another file than the original script.

When I run the script, I get

```
NameError: global name 'chain' is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's usually best to avoid globals when you can. Why do you need a global?

Comment: In this case, I am curious as to why it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`global` in Python means "within that module". It does not share names across modules.

If you want to access a variable defined in one module from another, simply import it:

```
from my_module import chain
```

or, even better, pass it as an argument to `func`.

Comment: If I import it, do I still need to keep `global` in the other module?

Comment: Only if you want to modify it within `func`.

Comment: Now I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "protein_prop.py", line 8, in <module>
    from neighborResidues import neighborResidues
  File "neighborResidues.py", line 9, in <module>
    from protein_prop import chain
  File "protein_prop.py", line 8, in <module>
    from neighborResidues import neighborResidues
ImportError: cannot import name neighborResidues`

where `protein_prop.py` is the original script that imports and calls `neighborResidues`, which in turn imports `chain` from `protein_prop`.

Comment: Well, you have a circular dependency now. Pass it as an argument instead.